# PHP using key of one array to access same key position on another array

Tags: php, arrays

I've looked at a number of suggestions for this, and they seem to rely on `array_combine()` which unfortunately is not suitable, as they arrays need to stay separate for other functions.

The arrays are set out as per

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 1 [2] => 3 ) 
Array ( [0] => 194 [1] => 0 [2] => 452 )
```

When I read in the first array, I get the key as `$key` and everything works fine.

Whenever I try and access the second array the whole script just whites out the page.

I want the code to work simliar to this ...

`$a2value = $a2[$key] => $value;
echo $a2value;`

Then I can do SQL lookups using `$a2value`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I don't understand it. Can you provide an example input => output?

Comment: `$a2value = $a2[$key]`?

Comment: do you want to loop $a1 array and want to get value of $a2 array from the key got from array $a1 ??

Comment: @u_mulder that's progress (as in its not white out the screen) although it's not using the `$key` variable or giving out the value for that key

Comment: @PrinceArora $a1 array is already looped and working properly, yes I want to use the $key that is got from $a1 to lookup within $a2

Comment: `they seem to rely on array_combine() which unfortunately is not suitable, as they arrays need to stay separate` - urr just set `$a3` to `array_combine($a1, $a2)`?

Answer (score 0):

Here Try this

let's suppose two arrays of same number of elements

```
  $a1=[1,2,3];
    $a2=[194,0,452];
    //A Simple foreach

   foreach($a1 as $key=>$a1value){
       $a2value=$a2[$key];
       //Perform Query here 
    }
```

Remember one thing number of elements of both array should always be equal or it will cause an error 
If you aren't certain about the size of both arrays then replace the line with this code

```
$a2value=empty($a2[$key]) ?  null : $a2[$key];
```

Hope this works !!!